# Native OSX Dictionary

Tags: macos, dictionary

Is there a native dictionary on OSX?

I would like to be able to click on a word (in any open window), and get its meaning in a quick popup windows.

Comment: If for any reason you can't select the word, bring up Spotlight (⌘-Space, or click the magnifying glass icon in the upper-right corner) and type the word in to the search box. The definition will be shown if it's in the dictionary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mouse over a word and tap the trackpad with three fingers, or enable the Dictionary service in System Preferences to assign a keyboard shortcut (by default, it's ⌃⌘D).

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! That's the tool I need.

Comment: Side note: by default, Mavericks assigns ⌃+⌘+D (control+cmd+D) to open the Dictionary for whatever word your cursor is currently over.