# Add languages to OSX dictionary

Tags: macos, language, internationalization, dictionary

The native OSX dictionary ([hover + 3-finger-tap](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142600/native-osx-dictionary)) does not work for the Hebrew language.

The example below shows its reluctance to interpret the word פרסומת, a valid Hebrew word.

Any ideas how to add extra languages to the dictionary?

[image]

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58823/how-to-switch-language-of-os-x-dictionary

Comment: Great picture. I'll link this to the duplicate but feel free to ping me if this is somehow different than the linked question in the end.

Comment: @bmike it is different, I want to add a language that isn't already there

Comment: So Hebrew isn't covered in is post? http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58833/5472 You can add any new dictionaries to /Library/Dictionaries... It's not clear if you are looking for recommendations on how to locate a proper hebrew dictionary or just wanted to know that you could add languages if you don't like the ones Apple supplies.

Comment: See if this page has a Hebrew dictionary to add:  http://clasquin-johnson.co.za/michel/mac-os-x-dictionaries/index.html

Comment: @TomGewecke All clear for a real answer :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This site has a number of extra dictionaries:

http://clasquin-johnson.co.za/michel/mac-os-x-dictionaries/index.html

and this article provides links for Hebrew/English and English/Hebrew

http://blog.jle.vi/post/72464439746/get-the-look-up-dictionary-feature-in-os-x-to-work

Answer (score 8):

Three-finger tap lookup is enabled by Dictionary.app.

`Dictionary -> Preferences` will enable you to activate more built-in dictionaries.

For more on adding dictionaries to Dictionary.app, [check out this article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easily-expanding-apple-dictionary-mac-only/) which also points out how to download and install third-party dictionaries.

Answer (score 5):

I was fed up with how hard it is to find good dictionaries if you don't speak one of the "big" languages that Apple supports (El Capitan adds a few very good dictionaries for German etc., but that's not very helpful for users in small(er) countries) and so I decided to do something about it and made an app for installing translation dictionaries: [Dictionaries](https://dictionaries.io).

Right now it has 44 languages (including Hebrew) and dictionaries are based on a good source (Wiktionary, periodically updated and growing steadily) and have stylesheets to look good in Yosemite and El Capitan. That's my two gripes with [clasqm's huge collection](http://clasquin-johnson.co.za/michel/mac-os-x-dictionaries/index.html) that Tom mentions: those are mostly old dictionaries, not updated for 10.10+'s more modern look and they are one-off conversions.

Comment: Works BUT contains quite limited dictionaries, and is a commercial product (*although very cheap, only a couple of dollars*)

Comment: @oori Out of curiosity, what language(s) did you try? The quality varies depending how popular a language is at Wiktionary, some are pretty good, some… ehm, less so.

Comment: hebrew 15k definitions