# Using the three finger tap Dictionary.app, is there a way to add an English to Chinese dictionary?

Tags: macos, internationalization, dictionary

As the topic states: Using the three finger tap word lookup, is there a way to add an English to Chinese dictionary? Or is there any available?

Comment: @ankii I am unclear if this answers the original question, Ronaldo is specifically looking for an English to Chinese translation dictionary, there are lots of apps that do this, but it's unclear ot me that just providing a Chinese or English dictionary actually solves the issue. Specifically I assume Ronaldo wants to be able to get a pop up of the word with a translation and native language description.

Comment: @unknowndomain you're seeing only Tom's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/142772/313842) there, not [second one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/142716/313842). See what Tom answered [below](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/381314/313842), it's the same :) Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58825/313842 this is the best one to answer it. So if you Close vote with it as target, this will get closed as dupe of both, like this:https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/381259/revisions

Comment: Gottcha @ankii!

Answer (score 0):

In MacOS, go to Applications/Dictionary/Preferences and check the box for the Chinese English item.

[image]